# $*$-isomorphism on $L(E)$

Tags: banach-algebras

Suppose $M_2$ be the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices and $L(M_2)$ be the set of all adjointable operators from $M_2$ to $M_2$.

Can you mention an example of$~~$$*-$isomorphism operator from $L(M_2)$ to $L(M_2)$? (not be identity map)

Comment: The identity map?

Comment: Apart from identity map.